# Django don't load imports

Tags: django, import

I have a trouble.
One of my computers (mac) have a problem.
All those imports are don't load. But another pc has no this bug

Already try to reinstall vs code, it's not helped me

```
from unicodedata import category
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.urls import reverse
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Comment: Did you create a virtual environment, and installed the necessary packages?

Comment: yes, it worked before, i will try again

Comment: I will switch the environment and it will work. thank you